# WebRTC: Bad Encoding Performance for Screensharing via CGDisplayStream (h264/vp8/vp9)

Tags: objective-c, swift, performance, encoding, webrtc

I am using the objective-c framework for WebRTC for building a screensharing app. The video is captured using CGDisplayStream. I have a working demo but at 2580x1080 I get only 3-4 fps. My googAvgEncodeMs is around 100-300ms (should be >10ms ideally) which explains why the screensharing is far from being fluid (30fsp+). I also switched between codecs (h264/vp8/vp9) but with all of them I get the same slow experience. The contentType in webRTC is set to screen (values: [screen,realtime]).

The cpu usage of my mac is then between 80-100%. My guess is that there is some major optimisation (qpMax, hardware-acceleration etc...) in the c++ code of the codecs that I have missed. Unfortunately my knowledge on codecs is limited.

Also interesting: Even when I lower the resolution to 320x240 the googAvgEncodeMs is still in the range of 30-60ms.

I am running this on a MacBook Pro 15 inch from 2018. When running a random webrtc inside Chrome/Firefox etc I get smoother results than with the vanilla webrtc framework.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC uses software encoding and that is the real culprit. Also encoding 2580 x 1080 in software is not going to be practical. Try reducing H and V resolution in half and it will improve performance with some loss in quality. Also if you are doing screen sharing and video support is not critical, you can drop frame rate to 10 frames per second. Logical solution is to figure out how to incorporate h/w acceleration.